# Expression type '@lvalue UIImage?' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting "Expression type '@lvalue UIImage?' is ambiguous without more context" error while setting tint color of image in IOS using swift 4.

```
cell.icon.image = cell.icon.image?.renderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

Is there anything i am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try like that ? `cell.icon.image = cell.icon.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)`

Comment: @AhmetSinaUstem Thanks that was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIImage.renderingMode` is a property, so you cannot call it like a function. You simply need to access the property of your cell and assign a new value to it.

```
cell.icon.image?.renderingMode = .alwaysTemplate
```

If you actually want to modify the `image` property itself instead of just changing its renderingMode, you need to call `withRenderingMode`.

```
cell.icon.image = cell.icon.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```